# In javascript how can I convert multiple arrays of two elements into key-values an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
arr = [['name', 'jack'],['age', 18],];
```

How do I convert it into the following by JavaScript?

```
{ name: 'jack', age: 18 }
```

Comment: Did you tried something ? What worked, what didn't ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Comment: //  The Old School
let obj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let key: string = ''
  let value: string = ''
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    if (j === 0) key = arr[i][j];
    else if (j === 1) value = arr[i][j];
  }
  obj[key] = value
}

Comment: //  The Noob
var tupleObjects = {}
arr.forEach(tuple => {
  var tupleObject = {}
  var i = 0
  do {
    switch (tuple[i]) {
      case "name":
        tupleObject = { 'name': tuple[1] };
        i++;
        break;
      case "age":
        tupleObject = { 'age': tuple[1] };
        i++;
        break;
      default:
        tupleObject = { '': null };
        i++;
        break;
    }
  } while (i == tuple.length)
  Object.assign(tupleObjects, tupleObject)
})

Comment: //  The Geek
const obj = arr.reduce((obj, curr) => obj.set(curr[0], curr[1]), new Map())

Comment: // ‍ The Admin
Object.fromEntries(arr)

Comment: //  The Copilot
(function convertTuplesToObject [press tab])
function convertTuplesToObject(tuples) {
  const obj = {}
  for (const [key, value] of tuples) {
    obj[key] = value
  }
  return obj
}

Answer (score 3):

```js
arr = [['name', 'jack'],['age', 18],];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(arr);

console.log(obj);

//{
//  "name": "jack",
//  "age": 18
//}
```